# ManyToMany mapping issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following domain objects:

```
public class UserSpecialization : PersonSpecialization, IUserSpecialization
{
    public static readonly string SpecializationNameValue = "User";

    public UserSpecialization()
    {
        Roles = new Collection<IRole>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<IRole> Roles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public abstract class PersonSpecialization : DomainObjectOfInt32, IPersonSpecialization
{
    public virtual IPerson Person { get; set; }
    public virtual string SpecializationName { get; protected set; }
}

public class Person : DomainObjectOfInt32, IPerson, IAuditable
{
    public Person()
    {
        Specializations = new List<IPersonSpecialization>();
    }

    public virtual IList<IPersonSpecialization> Specializations { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class Role : DomainObjectOfInt32, IRole, IAuditable
{
    public Role(string roleName)
        : this()
    {
        Name = roleName;
    }
    protected Role()
    {
        AssignedUsers = new Collection<IUserSpecialization>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<IUserSpecialization> AssignedUsers
    {
        get;
        protected set; }
}
```

My mapping is as follow:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    { 
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasMany<PersonSpecialization>(c => c.Specializations)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasManyToMany<UserSpecialization>(x => x.AssignedUsers).Table("UserRole");
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
    }
}

public class PersonSpecializationMap : ClassMap<PersonSpecialization>
{
    public PersonSpecializationMap()
    {
        Table("PersonSpecialization");

        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<string>("SpecializationName");

        Map(x => x.SpecializationName).ReadOnly();

        References<Person>(c => c.Person);
    }
}
```

Now when i select a Person, i get also all his roles in Roles collection. Also when saving a Role, all linked Persons are nicely saved.
But when i save a Person, the linked roles of that Person does not save.

How can i solve this issue?

The mapping of UserSpecialization :

```
public class UserSpecializationMap : SubclassMap<UserSpecialization>
{
   public UserSpecializationMap()
    {
        Table("User");

        DiscriminatorValue(UserSpecialization.SpecializationNameValue);

        Join("[User]", joined =>
        {
            joined.Map(c => c.UserName, "Username");

            joined.HasManyToMany<Role>(x => x.Roles).Inverse()
                .Table("UserRole");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide your code for saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing

```
public class UserSpecializationMap : SubclassMap<UserSpecialization>
{
    public UserSpecializationMap()
    {
        Table("PersonSpecialization");

        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        DiscriminatorValue("UserSpecialization");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles).Cascade.All()...;
    }
}
```

btw: i would use a polymorph property for the specializationName then you do not need to specially initialize the property, you can not forget it in a dervied class, it does not take space in the object.

```
// base class
public abstract string SpecializationName { get; }

// dereived class
public override string SpecializationName { get { return "User"; } }
```

Comment: Sorry i was forgot to add the UserSpecializationMap:   
public class UserSpecializationMap:SubclassMap<UserSpecialization>{public UserSpecializationMap(){Table("User");DiscriminatorValue(UserSpecialization.SpecializationNameValue);Join("[User]", joined =>{joined.Map(c => c.UserName,"Username");joined.HasManyToMany<Role>(x =>x.Roles).Inverse().Table("UserRole");});}} I removed the 'Inverse()' from it.Now when i try to save a Person(with roles linked),i get:Nhibernate.PropertyAccessException:Exception occurred getter of DO.DomainObjectOfInt32.Id. InnerException:Object does not match target type.

Comment: add the mapping to the question, it is almost unreadable in a comment